# Xpath expression to find non-child elements by attribute

Tags: xpath, attributes

here's a nice puzzle.  Suppose we have this bit of code:

```
<page n="1">
 <line n="3">...</line>
</page>
```

It is real easy to locate the **line** element "n=3" within the **page** element "n=1" with a simple xpath expression:  xpath(//page[@n='1')/line[@n='3']).  Great, beautiful, elegant.
Now suppose what we have is this encoding (folks familiar with the TEI will know where this is coming from).

```
<pb n="1"/>
(arbitrary amounts of stuff)
<lb n="3"/>
```

We want to find the **lb** element with n="3", which follows the **pb** element with n="1".  But note -- this **lb** element could be almost anywhere following the **pb**: it may not be (and most likely is not) a sibling, but could be a child of a sibling of the **pb**, or of the **pb**'s parent, etc etc etc.

So my question: how would you search for this **lb** element with n="3", which follows the **pb** element with n="1", with XPath?

Thanks in advance

Peter

Answer (score 2):

**Use**:

```
  //pb[@n='1']/following::lb[@n='2']
|
  //pb[@n='1']/descendant::lb[@n='2']
```

This selects any `lb` element that follows the specified `pb` in document order -- even if the wanted `lb` element is a descendant of the `pb` element.

**Do note** that ***the following expression doesn't in general select all wanted `lb` elements*** (it fails to select any of these that are descendants of the `pb` element):

```
  //pb[@n='1']/following::lb[@n='2']
```

**Explanation**:

As defined in the **[W3C XPath specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xpath-19991116/#axes)**, the `following::` and `descendant::` axes are non-overlapping:

> "*the following axis contains all nodes in the same document as the
>   context node that are after the context node in document order,
>   **excluding any descendants** and excluding attribute nodes and namespace nodes*"

Answer (score 1):

That would be

```
//pb[@n=1]/following::lb[@n=3]
```

Comment: Note that the `following` axis selects everything after the 
*closing* tag of the context node, so this would not match the `lb` if it were a *descendant* node of `pb`. However, according to your specifications, this is not a requirement.

Comment: Brilliant!so for a <lb n="2"/> following <cb n="a"/> following <pb n="1r"/> -- that is, line 2 in column a in page 1r, this should be:  //pb[@n=1r]/following::cb[@n=a]/following::lb[@n=2] ...yes?

Comment: Yes, but you indeed have to use quotes if your attribute values are strings, not numbers: `//pb[@n='1r']/following::cb[@n='a']/following::lb[@n='2']`

Comment: thanks! you solved a nice problem.  (question -- do all xpath systems support following::? have not seen that before

Comment: Yes, the `following` axis is defined in XPath 1.0: http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#axes